# How can I move an element to the last position in its flexbox container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, html-tag-details

I have a flexbox-container that includes several details-elements. They follow the flex-wrap behaviour. I want a details-element to jump below the other elements of the container, when it is opened.

So, it should go from this:

[image: flexbox before]

to this:

[image: flexbox after]

All details that are opened afterwards should behave the same way and jump into last position.
Until now, I have tried to change the order of the details-element which is clicked on with javascript/jQuery:

```js
$('details').click(function (event) {
   this.style.order="2";
   $('details').not(this).style.order="1";
});
```

```css
.container {
display:flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

details {
order: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

<details>
<summary>
first details
</summary>
<p>some details</p>
</details>

<details>
<summary>
second details
</summary>
<p>some details</p>
</details>

<details>
<summary>
third details
</summary>
<p>some details</p>
</details>

<details>
<summary>
fourth details
</summary>
<p>some details</p>
</details>

<details>
<summary>
fifth details
</summary>
<p>some details</p>
</details>

</div>
```

Do I need to give the details-elements a class for this and address them somehow? Or is there any other way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I made a couple of changes. This seems to get you what you're looking for. The added borders are for clarity. See the code below.

The trick is to set all `<details>` to the same order group. In this case I used 0. Then change the clicked `<details>` to `order: 1` (just needs to be a group number higher than the one assigned to all `<details>`).

Another somewhat tricky part is that to 'unset' the 'open' attribute on the open `<details>` you must use `removeAttr()` (jQuery) or `.removeAttribute` (vanilla JS).

And finally, lots of good info here [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details).

```js
$('details').click(function(event) {
  $('details').css({order: 0, width: "auto"}).removeAttr("open");
  $(this).css({order: 1, width: "100%"});
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

details {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1rem;
  order: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <details>
    <summary>
      first details
    </summary>
    <p>some details</p>
  </details>

  <details>
    <summary>
      second details
    </summary>
    <p>some details</p>
  </details>

  <details>
    <summary>
      third details
    </summary>
    <p>some details</p>
  </details>

  <details>
    <summary>
      fourth details
    </summary>
    <p>some details</p>
  </details>

  <details>
    <summary>
      fifth details
    </summary>
    <p>some details</p>
  </details>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is supposed to happen to all details opened afterwards you could add a class to `.container`

```js
$('details').click(function (event) {
   $('.container').addClass('details-below');
});
```

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container.details-below details {
  order: 2;
}
```